# how to replace view controllers instead push more segue

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4

how should I do in order to replace view controllers instead push more segue and fill up memory
I did try to replace it in storyBoard but it made the app crash.
any ideas?
maybe extension?

the popUP segue is almost perfect, its not fills up the memory but it put view on view instead just replace the old one

Comment: please elaborate your point

Comment: I would like to move between view controllers but when I do regular segue the memory is filled up so I want to replace the screen and not segue between.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you want to change the root view controller. Changing root view controller clears the navigation stack and deallocates the memory taken by VCs.

```
  // paste this in appDelegate or make it as an extension 

  func makeRootVC(storyBoardName : String, vcName : String) {

        let vc = UIStoryboard(name: storyBoardName, bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcName)
        let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
        nav.navigationBar.isHidden = true
        self.window?.rootViewController = nav
        let options: UIView.AnimationOptions = .transitionCrossDissolve
        let duration: TimeInterval = 0.6
        UIView.transition(with: self.window!, duration: duration, options: options, animations: {}, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I got this "Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'window'"

Comment: @itay When you are using Scene view then windows object is in the scene delegate. Copy window object and place it in the app delegate and it will work.

Comment: @iOSArchitect.com you should consider amending your answer to reflect your comment rather than leaving an vague comment as to what the possible answer may be.

Comment: @JamesPalfrey I don't think there is anything wrong with the answer and it definitely didn't deserve a downvote. If you want to improve the answer, please press the Edit button below the answer and do it yourself if you "really" want to help the community.